# Find a tag in XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to find a special tag which is equal to a player_name and then use the next tag's value(notes).The structure of XML file is :

> ```
> <Result>
>     <Name>Player1</Name>
>     <job>0<job>                 
>     <Age>10</Age>                   
>  </Result>
>  <Notepad>
>     <Name>Player1</Name>
>     <Notes>example notes....<Notes>
>  </Notepad>
> ```

I am using following code, but it does not return anything for "`x.getElementsByTagName("PlayerName").childNodes[i].nodeValue`" when i check it with alert.

```js
<script>
function myFunction(xml,player_name) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, notes;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Notepad")
  
 for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
     if (x.getElementsByTagName("Name").childNodes[i].nodeValue == player_name) {
        notes = x.getElementsByTagName("Notes").childNodes[i].nodeValue;
   
 document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = notes;}
     }     
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the above code with given xml content will throw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: x.getElementsByTagName is not a function

I have tested it. That's because ***Element.getElementsByTagName()*** method returns a live ***HTMLCollection*** of elements. To deal with a certain node from such collection you need to specify the node position directly.

```
function myFunction(xml, player_name) {
        var x, i, xmlDoc, notes;
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Notepad");

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[i].nodeValue == player_name) {
                notes = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Notes")[0].childNodes[i].nodeValue;

                document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = notes;
            }
        }
}
```

This works and gives me `example notes....` when calling `myFunction(xhttp.responseXML, 'Player1');`

Answer (score 1):

For your case xpath is better. I write this function for your purpose:

```
/**
 * This function assumes xml document
 * and player name as a arguments and
 * returns notes for this player if
 * this player exists false otherwise.
 *
 * @author Georgi Naumov
 * gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and
 * suggestions.
 */
function getPlayerNotes(xmlDoc, playerName) {
    var xpathQuery = [
        '//Notepad[Name[text()=\'',
        playerName,
        '\']]/Notes'
    ].join(''), recordsCount;

    recordsCount = xmlDoc.evaluate('count(' + xpathQuery + ')', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null);

    if (recordsCount.numberValue === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return (xmlDoc.evaluate(xpathQuery, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)).stringValue;
}
```

Here you can see demonstration how to use the function:

http://gonaumov.github.io/javaScriptXpath/

Also the input xml must be valid. Check example input string.